# Java Swing ActionListener not working and stopping constructor

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am using (or trying to) use the MVC Design Pattern. 
So I have a UI class that just minds its own business and a controller that, well, controlls the view.

When I register a ActionListener in the controller class it does not work. As debugging seems to show, the constructor does not even finsish after calling the constructor of a JDialog.

As describing does not make much senese, here are my classes:

This is the View:

```
    package view;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Timbo on 04.05.17.
 * This window will be used to authenticate library members and allow them to access staff functions
 */
public class AuthenticationWindow
{
    /**
     * The window that holds the authentication content
     */
    private JDialog _window;

    /**
     * This Panel holds the fields required for the input of username and password
     */
    private JPanel _textFieldPanel;

    /**
     * This panel will hold the buttons
     */
    private JPanel _buttonPanel;

    /**
     * The textfield in which the username can be entered
     */
    private JTextField _userName;

    /**
     * The field, in which the password can be entered
     */
    private JPasswordField _password;

    /**
     * Holds a string to hint for the username
     */
    private JLabel _usernameHint;

    /**
     * Holds a string to hint for the password
     */
    private JLabel _passwordHint;

    /**
     * A Button that will trigger the login process
     */
    private JButton _confirm;

    /**
     * A Button that will cancel the login process
     */
    private JButton _cancel;


    /**
     * Creates a new Authentication Window in which a user can authenticate to get staff clearance
     * @param parent The parent frame of this Window
     */
    public AuthenticationWindow(Frame parent)
    {
        //Initialize all the components
        _window = new JDialog(parent, "Please Authenticate", true);
        _textFieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        _buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        _userName = new JTextField();
        _password = new JPasswordField();
        _passwordHint = new JLabel("Password");
        _usernameHint = new JLabel("Username");
        _confirm = new JButton("Confirm");
        _cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

        //Assemble the textfield panel
        _textFieldPanel.add(_usernameHint);
        _textFieldPanel.add(_userName);
        _textFieldPanel.add(_passwordHint);
        _textFieldPanel.add(_password);

        //Assemble the button panel
        _buttonPanel.add(_cancel);
        _buttonPanel.add(_confirm);

        //Assemble the window
        _window.setLayout(new BoxLayout(_window.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        _window.add(_textFieldPanel);
        _window.add(_buttonPanel);

        //Configure the window
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        _window.setLocation(dim.width/2-_window.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-_window.getSize().height/2);
        _window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        _window.pack();

        //Show window
        _window.setVisible(true);
    }

    //All the getter methods for this class
    public JDialog getWindow()
    {
        return _window;
    }

    public JTextField getUsernameInput()
    {
        return _userName;
    }

    public JPasswordField getPasswordInput()
    {
        return _password;
    }

    public JButton getConfirm()
    {
        return _confirm;
    }

    public JButton getCancel()
    {
        return _cancel;
    }
}
```

This is the controller in charge of the view:

```
   package controller.start.viewController;

import view.AuthenticationWindow;
import view.ErrorScreen;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Observable;

/**
 * Created by Timbo on 05.05.17.
 * This is the controller class for the Authentication window. It handles updates and functionality for the view
 */
public class AuthenticationWindowController extends Observable
{
    private static final char[] PASSWORD = {'T', 'o', 'r', 'v', 'a', 'l', 'd', 's'};
    /**
     * The view that holds the components
     */
    private AuthenticationWindow _ui;

    /**
     * The parent frame of this view
     */
    private Frame _parent;

    public AuthenticationWindowController(Frame parent)
    {
        _ui = new AuthenticationWindow(parent);
        _parent = parent;
        registerListener();
    }

    private void registerListener()
    {
        _ui.getConfirm().addActionListener(e -> {checkInput();});
        _ui.getCancel().addActionListener(e -> {_ui.getWindow().dispose(); System.out.println("Window disposed");});
    }

    /**
     * This method checks the input and gives feedback to the user in case the input was wrong
     * If the input was correct the user is being authenticated as staff and can access the staff view in the start window
     */
    private void checkInput()
    {
        String username = _ui.getUsernameInput().getText();
        char[] password = _ui.getPasswordInput().getPassword();

        if (username.isEmpty())
        {
            new ErrorScreenController(_parent, ErrorScreen.USERNAME_ERROR);
        }
        else if (password.length == 0)
        {
            new ErrorScreenController(_parent, ErrorScreen.PASSWORD_ERROR);
        }
        else if ((username.equalsIgnoreCase("linus")) || (password.equals(PASSWORD)))
        {
            this.setChanged();
            this.notifyObservers();
        }
        else
        {
            new ErrorScreenController(_parent, ErrorScreen.WRONG_CREDENTIALS);
        }
    }
}
```

In the constructor the actionListeners just do not fire. 
If I set a breakpoint to the _parent = parent line the program only stops when I close the JDialoge that is the AuthenticationWindow.

The funny thing is I have two other classes that work in this manner. If need be I will post them here. Please let me know.

Thank you already for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the showing of a modal dialog "stops" the current thread, until the dialog will be closed. To avoid this problem you should redesign your application as followed:

1) Remove the line `_window.setVisible(true);` from constructor of `AuthenticationWindow`

2) Create a new method in `AuthenticationWindow` called `show`

```
public void show() {
    _window.setVisible(true);
}
```

3) Change the constructor of `AuthenticationWindowController`

```
public AuthenticationWindowController(Frame parent)
{
    _ui = new AuthenticationWindow(parent);
    _parent = parent;
    registerListener();
    _ui.show();
}
```

Some further hints:

First of all prefer [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to ActionListener. Secondary: your controller should not work with GUI widgets. So it's better to provide some high level method to your UI like `setValidator()` to transfer your validation functionality from controller into the UI (in this case you can create and register action directly in the UI). Also make the method to access password and login (not the fileds to input them).

Comment: Great! Thank you! I was not sure which method stops the thread. Would putting the Dialog in a new Thread do the same?

Comment: No. Swing is the single-thread lib. Please also read some further hints which I've added to my answer.